# Angular Digest issue with Directive. after is undefined $AnimateProvider</this.$get</<.enter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having issue with angular digest cycle.Could not find out what cause this.

Chrome Log

````
```angular.js:12783 TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
at Object.enter (angular.js:5280)
at ngRepeatTransclude (angular.js:28086)
at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7844)
at boundTranscludeFn (angular.js:7983)
at controllersBoundTransclude (angular.js:8593)
at ngRepeatAction (angular.js:28080)
at $watchCollectionAction (angular.js:16068)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16203)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16467)
at buildPageNumberList (ngPDFjs.js:92)```
````

Earlier it was working fine. Mean time i did merge my new big changes which broke it. some how $$childTail of $parent get changed to ChildScope to Scope. Which i think cause this issue.I am not sure though.

[image]

Fire Fox log:-

```
   Error: after is undefined
$AnimateProvider</this.$get</<.enter@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:14491:9
ngRepeatTransclude@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:37297:17
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:17055:29
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:17194:16
controllersBoundTransclude@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:17804:18
ngRepeatAction@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:37291:15
$watchCollectionAction@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25279:13
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25414:23
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25678:13
buildPageNumberList@http://localhost:3333/app.js:5386:13
promise callback*PDFDocumentLoadingTask_then@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:98684:14
loadPDF@http://localhost:3333/app.js:5374:13
handleSrcChanged@http://localhost:3333/app.js:5340:21
$CompileProvider/this.$get</Attributes.prototype.$set/<@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:16881:13
forEach@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:9552:11
$CompileProvider/this.$get</Attributes.prototype.$set@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:16879:24
interpolateFnWatchAction@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:18187:23
interpolateFnWatcher@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:20599:17
watchGroupAction@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25084:13
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25414:23
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25678:13
EventHandlerNonNull*createHttpBackend/<@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:20185:7
sendReq@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:20032:9
$http/serverRequest@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:19742:16
processQueue@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:24308:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:24324:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25570:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25386:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25678:13
EventHandlerNonNull*createHttpBackend/<@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:20185:7
sendReq@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:20032:9
$http/serverRequest@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:19742:16
processQueue@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:24308:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:24324:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25570:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25386:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:25678:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:10897:9
invoke@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:13771:14
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:10895:5
bootstrap@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:10915:12
angularInit@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:10809:5
@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:39025:5
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:3099:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:3211:7
.ready@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:3417:3
completed@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:3433:2
EventListener.handleEvent*jQuery.ready.promise@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:3451:4
@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:3461:1
@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:34:3
@http://localhost:3333/vendor.js:15:2
```

Comment: Can you provide some code or explain what kind of help you are looking for?

Comment: Finally i find out my custom directive scope get messed up when i add spinner from spinner.js to parent <div> of custom directive. This caused adding scope as sibling instead of child.  Which further lead to this error when $scope.$apply() get executed.To fix this i remove spinner from <div> create separate empty div for spinner.